# Monitoring and terminating a hanged process in Linux

Tags: linux, process, posix

I'm writing a script that runs many simultaneous processes that run the "dig" command. Once in a while (relatively rare, but happens in every run since I run dig many times) the dig command hangs with 0% CPU. Therefore, my script never terminates.
I've created a monitor process for each dig command I run, which terminates it after a while, but I was wondering if there isn't a simpler and more efficient way to run a process with a pre-determined "expiration date", i.e. if the process runs more then X seconds it gets a signal that terminates it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***timeout*** command :

**timeout 30s my_command my_args**

See man page for details.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!
P.S. I would vote the answer up, but I don't have enough reputation points. I'm new in town...:)

Answer (score 0):

The question is why is your dig process hanging the first place. Try running it under some debug tools like ltrace and strace, or even under ddd and see *why* it's hanging. If you find anything unusual post it as bug, it's the only way open source software gets better.

Dig should time out , however something may be broken on your network.

Comment: The hung processes are waiting on sigsuspend().
kill -SIGIO <pid> releases them causing them to terminate.
I'm not sure why they get there, but it might be related to too many digs running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the timeout options `dig` has, eg `+time=T` , +tries=T`etc. see the`dig` man page for more